# What are the limits of E.T.'s telekinesis abilities?

Tags: et-the-extra-terrestrial

During the film, we see E.T.  move several things by telekinesis several times, such as with the apples to represent planets, and then later the bike, and then at the end of the film

> five boys on bikes.

Are there limitations to this ability? Is there a maximum weight that he can lift or something?